# How to update Facebook fanspage status using REST API

Tags: facebook

I have created a IFacebookRestClient object in my JAVA web application and I have posted strings on my fanspage using `stream.publish()` method. But it seems to be "Recent Posts by Others on 'myFansPage'". The update message will not shown on my fans news feed.

So, I need to update status of my fanspage. How it is possible?

When I went through the Rest API, I could see the method "status.set()" and "users.setStatus()" but it posts only in users profile not on a fanspage.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the token of your page.

See https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

Then use the token from your page and set a regular status update.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Where I use the access_token ? Could you please provide a sample.

Comment: You use the app access tokens in the same way that you use the regular auth token. Obviously while using an app token you have a few less things available to you.